# Exclude the hidden elements from limitTo in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Need Help.Here is the solution I have been looking for..
 I am trying to show 6 elements from an array excluding the hidden elements. ie: If there are two hidden elements technically it will have to show 8 elements. I dont want to increment the scope object bound to limitTo as it is doing lot of complication. Is there any way that I can use a filter to keep the limitTo to a constant and bypassing limitTo filter if the element is hidden. I have been looking for the solution for a couple of days. Nothing worked out yet. I would really appreciate if someone can help on this.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="user in vm.userList | limitTo: '6" ng-hide="user.checked">

  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.checked"> {{user.name}}</input>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change a bit approach. Instead of `ng-hide` use `filter` please see sample below

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('fCtrl', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.userList = [


    {
      name: 1,
      checked: true
    }, {
      name: 2,
      checked: false
    }, {
      name: 3,
      checked: true
    }, {
      name: 4,
      checked: false
    }, {
      name: 5,
      checked: false
    }, {
      name: 6,
      checked: false
    }, {
      name: 7,
      checked: false
    }, {
      name: 8,
      checked: false
    }, {
      name: 9,
      checked: false
    }, {
      name: 10,
      checked: false
    }, {
      name: 11,
      checked: false
    },


  ];

  return vm;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="fCtrl as vm">

    <div data-ng-repeat="user in vm.userList | filter: {checked:false}| limitTo: 6">

      {{$index+1}})
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.checked">{{user.name}}</input>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thanks a lot You saved my hours of work.